# Using I2C and the adapters

Tags: gpio, pi-3, i2c, c

I am trying to use the GPIO pins for I2C communication between the master and the slaves and have been using this [page](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface) as a reference for me on how to do it. The code is run from userspace daemon.

So how do you pick the right adapter which has the GPIO pins?

I'm using [TCA9548A Switch](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9548a.pdf) which has address range between 0x70 to 0x77 but isn't the LSB the one which defines if the operation is read or write so how come the address can use the LSB because isn't 0x77 in binary 0111 0111?

Or do you just skip the operation addition to the address when calling ioctl() and the read() or write() functions handle that for you?

Answer (score 0):

I2C addresses are 7 bits or 10 bits in length.  10 bit devices are presumably pretty specialised as I have never come across one.

You will only see 7-bit address devices on the Pi.

The 7 bit address is sent in the top 7 bits of the I2C control byte.  The least significant bit in the control byte determines whether it is an I2C read (bit set) or write (bit clear).

Comment: So where exactly does the address get shifted by 1 to the left and the operation added to the address byte? And how do you choose the right adapter? I have read before what you wrote.

Comment: That depends on the library used.  If using the Linux driver it will be handled by the driver.  Typically from C you would open the device (`/dev/i2c-1` typically) and use ioctl 0x703 on the file descriptor to set the address.  You would then use read() and write() on the file descriptor.